# ¿Alguien me explica que traza hace el codigo de Fibonacci recursivo en Java?

Tags: java, algoritmos, recursión

Buenas.
Estoy tratando de dibujar la traza que sigue este codigo de fibonacci recursivo en Java para ver como funciona exactamente en este caso la recursividad.
No acabo de entender el funcionamiento exacto en este caso concreto puesto que en el return se supone que se devuelve y se sale de la funcion en la que está pero en el return se entra recursivamente a 2 métodos que a su vez si no es 0 ni uno devuelve otra vez 2 metodos recursivos saliendo de ese metodo en cuestión.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public int fibonacci(int n) {

  if ((n == 0) || (n == 1)) // base cases
      return n;
    else
      // recursion step
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Alguien podría explicarme la traza que sigue el programa y en cada pasada el resultado de n al terminar cada función por cada vez que es llamada?

El return realmente hace que no haya un stack saliendo de la función y llamando a su vez a 2 funciones a modo de recursión de cola?

Comment: Puedes ir imprimiendo mensajes para ir viendo la traza tu mismo, no ?

Comment: Que es lo que te falla realmente? Es un metodo un poco raro la verdad

Comment: @lois6b 
Lo que me rompe la cabeza es la parte de return fibonaaci(n-´1) + fibonacci(n-2);

Comment: @Lorthas si, la verdad es que es la primera vez que veo que se devuelva un metodo. Comprendo lo que intenta hacer, es como un procedimiento recursivo en pl/sql pero nose si en java es posible hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para entender el algoritmo, podemos empezar por los casos base e ir subiendo:

```
fibonacci(0) --> 0
fibonacci(1) --> 1
```

Para `fibonacci(2)` tenemos que aplicar la parte del `else`:

```
fibonacci(2) --> fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)
```

Para calcular la suma, hace falta conocer el resultado de las dos llamadas que, en el caso de suma, se evalúan de izquierda a derecha. Por tanto tenemos la siguiente secuencia:

```
fibonacci(2)
--> fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)
--> 1 + fibonacci(0)
--> 1 + 0
--> 1
```

Para `fibonacci(3)`:

```
fibonacci(3)
--> fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)
--> (fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)) + fibonacci(1)
--> (1 + fibonacci(0)) + fibonacci(1)
--> (1 + 0) + fibonacci(1)
--> 1 + fibonacci(1)
--> 1 + 1
--> 2
```

Este último caso puedes observar que `fibonacci(1)` es invocado dos veces. Cuando mayor sea el número entero, más veces se repetirán los cálculos. (Un modo de optimización sería guardar el resultado para posteriores cálculos (["memoization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization))).

El proceso es bastante lineal, primero una función y luego la otra. No hay mezcla de stacks ya que las funciones no se invocan simultáneamente.

Haciendo un ejercicio de imaginación, para calcular `fibonacci(n)` no necesitas más de `n` niveles de recursividad, lo que es lo mismo, no más de `n` *"stackframes"*.

Answer (score 5):

Supongamos que ingresamos el número 3.

Como no es 0 ni 1 pasa al `else {`

Una vez dentro del `else` tenemos por seguro que el resultado sera la suma de `fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)`, ejeplificando con un diagrama bien podría quedar de la siguiente forma

--------?(3)

------/------\

----?(2)------?(1)

Donde no sabemos el resultado "?" pero si el número que vamos a ingresar, se ejecuta el primer fibonacci del diagrama de la segunda linea `fibonacci(n-1)` que es `fibonacci(2)`, al no ser 0 ni 1 pasa al `else` donde se ejecutará de nuevo `fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)`, el diagrama nos quedaría ahora así

--------?(3)

------/------\

----?(2)------?(1)

--/----\

-?(1)---?(0)

Ejecutando el primer fibonacci de la 3 linea `fibonacci(n-1)` que es 2 - 1 = 1 `fibonacci(1)`, al ejecutarlo y ser 1, nos regresa n que es 1, entonces ya sabemos que regresa `fibonacci(1)`

--------?(3)

------/------\

----?(2)------?(1)

--/----\

-1(1)---?(0)

Al ejecutar el segundo fibonnacci de la tercera linea `fibonacci(n-2)` que es 2 - 2 = 0 `fibonacci(0)` nos regresará 0, dado que regresa n y n

--------?(3)

------/------\

----?(2)------?(1)

--/----\

-1(1)---0(0)

Ahora sabemos que `fibonacci(2)` regresa `fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)` que es 1 + 0 = 1

--------?(3)

------/------\

----1(2)------?(1)

--/----\

-1(1)---?(0)

Pasamo al segundo fibonacci de la segunda linea que sabemos que `fibonacci(1)` = 1, entonces.

--------?(3)

------/------\

----1(2)------1(1)

--/----\

-1(1)---0(0)

Nuevamente sabemos que `fibonacci(3)` regresa `fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)` que es 1 + 1 =

--------2(3)

------/------\

----1(2)------1(1)

--/----\

-1(1)---0(0)

Pero como dijeron lo mejor sería debuggear o con simples prints te puede servir

Answer (score 0):

Para ver la traza por ti mismo podrias usar el debugger de java o si no puedes mostrar en la consola lo que haces:

```
public int fibonacci(int n) {

  if ((n == 0) || (n == 1)) // base cases
       System.out.println("Devuelvo +"n)
       return n;
    else
       System.out.println("Entro en el else con +"n)      
        // recursion step
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Aunque puedes usar otros metodos para la serie fibonacci

```
public class fibonacci
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
int a=0,b=1,c,hasta,i;
cantidad=15; //indica la cantidad de numeros en la serie fibonacci


for(i=0;i<hasta;i++)
{
c=a+b;
a=b;
b=c;
System.out.print(" "+a);
}
}

}
```

Comment: con "Es un metodo un poco raro" te referias a que usa la [`recursion`](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=recursion&*)?

Comment: Eso es, usa una recursion como si estubiera en un procedimiento recursivo de pl/sql nose si es posible en java

Comment: @lois6b Lo que intentaba precisamente es entender la recursión en todos sus casos, porque en casos simples se como funciona, pero en un caso más enrevesado como este me cuesta más verlo.

Comment: Solo mi opinión, pero esto me parece un largo comentario, mas bien que una respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: la recursion no es de un lenguaje/tecnologia solo. es parte de la programacion funcional , en contraposicion de la imperativa. Piensa en la multiplicacion. Puedes hacer un bucle For (manera imperativa) que sume (3+3+3+3+...)  o puedse hacer una recursion (manera funcional)

Comment: @lois6b seguramente tengas razón, yo he asociado la recursion directamente a pl/sql porque es donde aprendi el concepto, ademas de que nunca lo habia llebado a java en el ambito personal o profesional, me ha parecido cuanto menos curioso.

Comment: @Lorthas yo tampoco comprendo muy bien como funciona esta recursion, lo que yo haria para comprender paso a paso como funciona es usar el debugger de java

Comment: Estoy intentando desgranarlo a ver que pasos hace.

Comment: @lorthas yo te recomendaria hacer el metodo recursivo para la multiplicacion si la recursion es lo que quieres entender. porque con fiboncci tienes que entender a parte de la recursion , como funciona la secuencia..

Comment: @Lorthas perfecto, mucha suerte y a ver si consigues el resultado esperado, si lo haces no estaria mal que te respondieras a ti mismo ( que ahora me has dejado con la curiosidad de saber como funciona)